# Germany short term overstay visa by mistake

Tags: visas, germany, overstaying

I was in Germany last month to visit my wife on visitors visa. My visa duration was 45 days but maximum allowable days were 30 which I failed to read accurately on my visa. I stayed there for 37 days considering visa duration of 45 days which is big mistake I made being educated.

They stopped me during my return at Frankfurt airport and told me you have overstayed. They gave me some papers and informed me that you will receive letter regarding fine or action on your home address.

I am worried about this because next time I have to apply for family reunion visa for Germany as my wife is about to settled over there.

My question is how much fine they will impose on me
What should I do to accept my mistake
So that my next visa will not reject

Comment: No one can say for sure what they will decide. Often such short overystays are closed with no further action. You will recieve a letter telling you this.

Comment: Family reunion visa shouldn't be affected in any case for minor problems.

Comment: Siumilar question: [Overstay in Germany - repercussions on future family reunion visa application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147373/overstay-in-germany-repercussions-on-future-family-reunion-visa-application?rq=1)

Comment: Within how many days I will receive that letter??? After paying fine if any I should write them to accept my mistake or not through any lawyer of Germany??