Overstayed Schengen Visa by a day
My Schengen visa was approved for 9 days stay but I did not know it, I thought I could stay for entire visa duration which was 3 months. So unknowingly I overstayed for a day and while returning German officials gave me some documentation and charged criminal act against me and ask me to email them when I go back to my home country. What could happen now, would they penalize me, can I apply for Schengen tourist visa again in future?

It would be helpful to upload the documentation you have here, with personal data masked.

I doubt "charged criminal act". An officer cannot do it: it requires a judge and (if possible) they need to get your explanation. Note: I do not mean that other actions (which officers can apply) are not powerful. I expect a ban can be set by them. -- I think they may warned you that next time you risk a criminal charge.

Possible duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184065/overstayed-my-visa-in-germany-by-9-days

Interesting that this so often seems to happen in Germany out of 20+ EU countries?

@GiacomoCatenazzi If you overstay in Germany, you will usually be reported to the police for staying in Germany illegally. Usually these proceedings are them closed by the prosecutor some months later.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I don't know the vocabulary in Italian, and I don't know the details of German criminal procedure, but in English, at least in most jurisdictions, a "charge" is an accusation made by police and/or a government attorney which is subsequently evaluated ("tried") by a court.  "Charging" is the process of presenting evidence of an offense to the court.  The thing that may be done only by a judge (or, in a jury trial, only by a jury) is to "convict" the defendant.  For this sense of charge in Italian, Wiktionary gives accusa or imputazione.

@phoog: ok, it makes more sense.

@GiacomoCatenazzi  This would a violation of the residence act (AufenthG) and not the criminal act (StGB). The police write the charges and sends that to the prosecutor who decides if it in the public interest to pursue. If yes, formal charges are made and goes to court, otherwise dropped. Since such an overystay leave a 'paper trail', the police (Bundespolizei) are required to write the charges.

@Jan The reason is probably that German police has very little leeway in evaluating the relevance of a criminal violation and is in most cases obligated to initiate a criminal investigation if they know of one. The case must go to a prosecutor or a judge before it can be potentially decided that the violation is so irrelevant, that the case can be dismissed and that can also only be done if the violated law does not foresee a minimum penalty. In many other countries, the police is entitled to make such decisions themself.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo Looks like it might make sense to turn occasional minor overstaying into an Ordnungswidrigkeit (infraction) rather than a Straftat (crime).

@Jan The Schengen Border Code does not make a distinction between the two. As long as that is the case the domestic laws (that implement the Schengen Border Code) cannot do so either.

@Jan Also, as meantion previously, this is a violation of the residence act (AufenthG) and therefore cannot be definded as a Straftat (defined in the StGB) or (re-)clasified as an Ordnungswidrigkeit since it also not defined in the OWiG (Gesetz über Ordnungswidrigkeiten).

Tor-Einar is right about the reason why it comes up so frequently with Germany. In actual fact, the Schengen Borders Code says absolutely nothing about all this and lets member countries completely free to deal with the issue appropriately. As usual, Germany manages to tie itself into knots for something all other member states are able to handle without fuss.

I am curious: How did you get into the country and how did you get out? German border, from what I've seen, always asks tourists when they'll leave, even proof at times. Did you move your return flight back? Because that may affect how this goes.

Short answer re. penalty: From what I have heard from people with similar problems, criminal proceedings for short accidental overstays are usually closed without penalty because of lack of public interest. Not sure about future visa applications.

This is certainly consistent with what I've heard, but the answer would be more helpful if you could describe in a little more detail the source of your knowledge ("what I know").  Do you have personal experience or first-hand knowledge of people who have experienced this?

@phoog done (from people with a similar problem)

If there is no penalty, there is no basis to enter an alert in the SIS, which is until now the main mechanism to make sure an overstay has consequences on subsequent visa applications. The only thing left once the charges have been dropped are the stamps (and soon, the record in the EES).
